# Cannot delete a SFTP file using cURL

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I have a weird issue with deleting or using `rm` with cURL. It works just fine when I try to delete or move files using the same credentials on FileZilla, but doesn't work when running it through cURL. Do I have any issues with my code?

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sftp_server.$file_name);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$user_pwd);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS,CURLPROTO_SFTP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_QUOTE, array('rm ~/folder/' . $file_name));

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I also don't have any issues downloading SFTP files using cURL.

When I `var_dump()` the curl result I get a permission denied "**curl: (21) rm command failed: Permission denied**".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If works fine with same credentials than FileZilla, then it looks like a permissions issue.

Comment: @Triby That's what I thought, but permissions at what level? The PHP server? And what should I look for?

Comment: I think is about server permissions (Apache, IIS, nginx), usually only `root user` and file owner can delete files.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? What kind of response are you getting?

Comment: @ArSeN It doesn't delete the file, and shows that permission denied, but when I use FileZilla I don't get the error and I'm able to successfully delete the files.

Comment: "shows that permission denied"? Can you say what exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @ArSeN **curl: (21) rm command failed: Permission denied**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reach a solution using a different way to connect to SFTP by using `ssh2_sftp` and not cURL. Here is a snippet of the code I used if anyone can benefit from it:

```html
$connection = ssh2_connect('SFTP-Server-name', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

ssh2_sftp_unlink($sftp, $file_path.$file_name);
```